# How do I check how many times a group of value has appeared under a certain date/weekday in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want a way to check the max and the min times a ticket has been called at a certain weekday (eg: Monday: 5 tickets max; 2 min), the ticket has an ID that ranges between 0 and 4 so I want them all to be noticed.

This is what I currently have:

```
int S = 0;
var senhas = _db.SenhaSet.ToList();
double[] countersemana = new double[20];

foreach (var senha in senhas)
{
    if (senha.Data.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday && senha.IdTipoSenha >= 0)
    {
        S++;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not add all of monday's ticket into a `List` then find the `Max()` and `Min()` from the List?

Comment: yeah, but how can i then find what monday had the most ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very inefficient as it relies on returning the entire SenhaSet table from the database and then looping round it. You want to apply the filter via Entity Framework on the database. Something like (I don't know your column names so am guessing):

```
var senhas = _db.SenhaSet
    .Where(s => SqlFunctions.DatePart("dw", s.Data) == DayOfWeek.Monday && IdTipoSenha >= 0)
    .GroupBy(s => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.Data))
    .Select(s => new {
        TicketDate= s.Key,
        Count = s.Count(t => t.IdSenha)
    })
    .ToList();

int maxTickets = senhas.Max(s => s.Count);
int minTickets = senhas.Min(s => s.Count);
```

This assumes the database is SQL Server in order to use the System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.DatePart method.

Comment: what is the t.Id going to ?

Comment: It's just counting the number of tickets for that date - I'm just assuming a unique ID called "Id".

Comment: so just a local variable or something in the database ?

Comment: I'm assuming it's a column in the SenhaSet table. As I don't know anything about your database schema I'm just guessing column names but the general logic should hold.

Comment: got the error " cannot implicity convert 'int' to 'bool'

Comment: I've amended the query using the schema in your link. It relies on SQL Server-specific function so hope that is your RDBMS!